# Does the ASP.NET Development Server (a.k.a. Cassini) support SSL?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, cassini

We are trying to get our .NET devs to use the [ASP.NET Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (VS2008) for web development instead of a local instance of [IIS](http://www.iis.net/).

I received this response as a reason why some of our devs can't use it:
"Our XXXX Online Sales application uses SSL to protect passwords. While Visual Studio does permit some basic web application development without IIS, the light weight replacement does not support SSL."

Does this make sense? Is there a work-around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web server built into VS doesn't not support SSL.  It is meant to be a quick way to test an application.  For SSL, you would need to use IIS and get a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a possible approach- if you just want to run ASP.NET programs with SSL, you can use Cassini + Apache Http Proxy/Nginx for Windows. But if you are on Windows XP beware there might have limitations on concurrent connections.

Comment: you got an example of that?