# Does Utidev Cassini support SSL?

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, cassini

I know that IIS supports SSL.

However, we have a use case that we are evaluating [Utidev Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/) for. However, I do not know if ultra cassini supports SSL. Does it?

Comment: Is this a duplicate question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187593/does-vs2008-built-in-web-server-cassini-support-ssl)

Comment: Do you mean [Ultidev's Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/)?

Comment: @Steve, I don't think so. The asker is unclear, but I assume he refers to one of the many Cassini derivative products.

Comment: @Justin, yes UlltiDev's Cassini

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a ssl proxy like [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) on top of cassini.

Answer (score 0):

Ulti dev cassni does not support SSL.

SSL is possible with ultra cassini by use of HttpVPN proxy http://ultidev.com/products/HttpVPN/index.htm[enter link description here](http://ultidev.com/products/HttpVPN/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

UltiDev Cassini does not support SSL, but its upcoming replacement product, [UWS Pro](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst633_Welcome-to-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro.aspx), [will support SSL](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst659_UWS-Screenshots.aspx) in the near future.

Comment: can u tell me what is the difference between Cassini and ultidev Cassini