# WCF service from class library "view in browser" command with https

Tags: wcf

I have a Class library with WCF service added. When I click on command **View in Browser** it opens with http prefix. Is there a way how to open it with https prefix without hosting it on iis ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 'Cassini' or the web server built into VS, then [SSL is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187593/does-vs2008-built-in-web-server-cassini-support-ssl).  But if you change your web settings (by choosing Properties from your project), you can host in IIS.  IISExpress might support it, but again requires a change to the project settings.

Comment: ok, so as i understand the best way is still to create a web site project with wcf service template and host it on iis